# How to split Ember routes into multiple namespaces?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have two Ember apps whose functionality partially overlaps, so I want to extract the common parts into a separate module of sorts. This extracted module contains routes, controllers, views, etc... - all of them defined in their own namespace, let's say `Shared`:

```js
Shared = Ember.Namespace.create();

Shared.FooRoute = Ember.Route.extend({ /*...*/ })
Shared.FooController = Ember.Controller.extend({ /*...*/ })

// ...
```

My question is, how do I tell Ember to look the routes (controller, views, ...) up in the `Shared` namespace in addition to the default `App` namespace?

```js
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("foo"); // <-- how to tell it I want Shared.FooRoute, 
                     //     not App.FooRoute?
})
```

Also, I don't want to "mount" the shared routes under any route prefix. I don't want the `Shared.FooRoute` to have path `shared/foo`, but only `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. One can affect the way Ember resolves the routes (and other objects) by providing a customized [resolver](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.DefaultResolver.html). This is what I did:

```js
App = Ember.Application.create({
  resolver: Ember.DefaultResolver.extend({
    resolveOther: function(parsedName) {
      // try default resolution...
      var result = this._super(parsedName);

      if (result) {
        return result;
      } else if (parsedName.root != Shared) {
        // if it fails, look in the Shared namespace
        parsedName.root = Shared;
        return this.resolveOther(parsedName);
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }
  })
})
```